# Export and use Keras model in Tensorflow 1.0 - is there a simple example out there?

Tags: c++, keras, keras-layer

Apologies for what I'm sure is a rookie question but I'm a bit new to machine learning.

I'm wondering what the right way is to export and use a Sequential model built in Keras for use in Tensorflow. I've poured over all possible resources and have come across a lot of un-clear or seemingly un-related information.

My goal is to export and use a trained model in Tensorflow's c++ api, NOT Tensorflow serving which seems to be the closest thing to a definitive example of export and use of a model in Tensorflow.

To split this up a bit so it's hopefully easier to digest

1. What's the correct way to export the model? I've seen at least 2 different ways from exporting and importing a `MetaGraph` to using a `SavedModel` object, it's unclear what the right method is.
2. Once I export the model it's not clear how I might run any new operations against it. It looks like a lot of operations and variables are exported which makes it a bit confusing. I suppose to sum it up a bit better, for example, what would the tensorflow equivalent of `model.predict` be?

I have a simple model here in Keras that just multiplies an input by 2 that can be used as an example if it helps. I believe it's set up correctly, I'm not entirely sure whether the resulting shape is correct but the operation appears to work.

https://gist.github.com/sortofsleepy/b17417e2cbca1a39d33b32d325f07995

Help is appreciated! Thanks!